# Why are these concentric parts fusing together at seam lines?

Tags: prusaslicer, stringing

The print is a collapsible sword I'm using as a test. Everything seems fine on the outside, but inside it seems the segment parts of the sword inside the hilt are fusing together at the seam lines causing them to stick together.

**Model**: https://thangs.com/designer/3dprintingworld/3d-model/Collapsing%20Katana-22696

**Finished Print** (looks fine)
[image]

**Concentric blade pieces** (fuse marks that I sheared off and broke to get out)
[image]

**Seams on exterior of hilt look great**
[image]

**Print settings/info**

**Printer**: Prusa MK3S+

**Slicer**: PrusaSlicer 2.5.0a3

**Settings preset**: 0.15 mm QUALITY

**Filament**: Prusa PLA

**Nozzle temp**: 205 °C (default is 215 °C, but lower eases stringing and has never been a problem for many past prints)

**Nozzle size**: 0.4 mm

**Full config**: https://pastebin.com/ECa6KkYK

Comment: Just to make sure, did you print the whole sword as a print-in-place? If I follow the link to the print files it shows that the prints are printed apart from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I found that the issue was stringing due to excess moisture in the filament from being stored outside of a sealed low-humidity container for long periods.

After placing it in a heated dehydrator for 2 days, my next print had low stringing and did not bond interlaced parts together significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You did well to decrease the temperature. You could go even lower to 200°C
As you noticed, You really have a little bit of stringing between the elements. That's what binds the parts together. Many times when you print only a single part this will be no problem. With many nested parts, you retraction really has to be set to optimal values.

Try increasing the retraction distance in the slicer.

Comment: I did try that before the post, but thank you for posting. I believe I found the reason for it which was excess moisture in the filament because after doing a "baking" session I was able to reduce the stringing that was causing this.